# How I can define different css files for different browsers in asp.net?

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, css, cross-browser

How I can define css files for different browsers? For Example I want that if a User use the firefox that a div is width='1000px' and if a User use IE 7- 9 or higher have a div witdh='800px'.

I work with ASP.NET and C#. What can I do if I want make a Application for more Browser?

Comment: try using browser prefixes. Like -webkit-width for chrome and -mox-width for firefox.

Comment: @SamarthAgarwal — Prefixes are only supported for *experimental* properties. `width` is consistently implemented and standard.

Answer (score 1):

You want to use condicional css by each caste this maybe help you

http://css-tricks.com/how-to-create-an-ie-only-stylesheet/